# EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text); возвращает null

Tags: java, android

Весь этот список инициализируется как null, а это проблема. Объясните почему так?

```
        EditText  passwordEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordEdit);//=null
        EditText emailEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailEdit);//=null
        EditText questionEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.questionEdit);//=null
        EditText answerEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.answerEdit);//=null
        EditText  nicknameEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nicknameEdit);//=null
```

java файл

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class EditProfile extends AppCompatActivity {


    public String log;
    public String avatar;
    String type;

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.edit_profile);


        Intent intent = getIntent();
        log = intent.getStringExtra("log");
        avatar = intent.getStringExtra("avatar");


        ImageView img_ava = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ava);
        img_ava.setClipToOutline(true);//для закругления
        Button btn_edit_email = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_edit_email);
        Button btn_edit_login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_edit_login);
        Button btn_edit_name = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_edit_name);
        Button btn_edit_password = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_edit_password);

        EditText  passwordEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordEdit);
        EditText emailEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailEdit);
        EditText questionEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.questionEdit);
        EditText answerEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.answerEdit);
        EditText  nicknameEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nicknameEdit);


        ImageView btn_back = findViewById(R.id.image_back);
        btn_back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent back = new Intent (EditProfile.this, MainProfile.class);
                back.putExtra("log",log);
                back.putExtra("avatar",avatar);
                startActivity(back);
                finish();
            }
        });


        img_ava.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Dialog dialog_edit_ava;
                dialog_edit_ava = new Dialog(EditProfile.this);
                dialog_edit_ava.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
                dialog_edit_ava.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_edit_ava); 
                dialog_edit_ava.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT)); //прозрачный фон диалогового окна
                dialog_edit_ava.setCancelable(false); 

                ImageView img_ava_lamb = (ImageView)dialog_edit_ava.findViewById(R.id.ava_lamb);
                ImageView img_ava_owl = (ImageView)dialog_edit_ava.findViewById(R.id.ava_owl);
                ImageView img_ava_panda = (ImageView)dialog_edit_ava.findViewById(R.id.ava_panda);
                ImageView img_ava_penguin = (ImageView)dialog_edit_ava.findViewById(R.id.ava_penguin);
                ImageView img_ava_pig = (ImageView)dialog_edit_ava.findViewById(R.id.ava_pig);
                ImageView img_ava_rabbit = (ImageView)dialog_edit_ava.findViewById(R.id.ava_rabbit);
                ImageView img_ava_sloth = (ImageView)dialog_edit_ava.findViewById(R.id.ava_sloth);


                img_ava_lamb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        avatar = "0";
                        type = "avatarChange";
                        BackgroundWorkerAvatar backgroundWorkerA = new BackgroundWorkerAvatar(EditProfile.this);
                        backgroundWorkerA.execute(type, log, avatar);

                        

                        dialog_edit_ava.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                img_ava_owl.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        avatar = "1";
                        type = "avatarChange";
                        BackgroundWorkerAvatar backgroundWorkerA = new BackgroundWorkerAvatar(EditProfile.this);
                        backgroundWorkerA.execute(type, log, avatar);

                       
                        dialog_edit_ava.dismiss(); 
                    }
                });

                img_ava_panda.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        avatar = "2";
                        type = "avatarChange";
                        BackgroundWorkerAvatar backgroundWorkerA = new BackgroundWorkerAvatar(EditProfile.this);
                        backgroundWorkerA.execute(type, log, avatar);


                       

                        dialog_edit_ava.dismiss(); 
                    }
                });

                img_ava_penguin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        avatar = "3";
                        type = "avatarChange";
                        BackgroundWorkerAvatar backgroundWorkerA = new BackgroundWorkerAvatar(EditProfile.this);
                        backgroundWorkerA.execute(type, log, avatar);


                       

                        dialog_edit_ava.dismiss(); 
                    }
                });

                img_ava_pig.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        avatar = "4";
                        type = "avatarChange";
                        BackgroundWorkerAvatar backgroundWorkerA = new BackgroundWorkerAvatar(EditProfile.this);
                        backgroundWorkerA.execute(type, log, avatar);

                       
                        dialog_edit_ava.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                img_ava_rabbit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        avatar = "5";
                        type = "avatarChange";
                        BackgroundWorkerAvatar backgroundWorkerA = new BackgroundWorkerAvatar(EditProfile.this);
                        backgroundWorkerA.execute(type, log, avatar);


                        

                        dialog_edit_ava.dismiss(); 
                    }
                });

                img_ava_sloth.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        avatar = "6";
                        type = "avatarChange";
                        BackgroundWorkerAvatar backgroundWorkerA = new BackgroundWorkerAvatar(EditProfile.this);
                        backgroundWorkerA.execute(type, log, avatar);


                        

                        dialog_edit_ava.dismiss(); 
                    }
                });


               
                TextView btn_close = (TextView) dialog_edit_ava.findViewById(R.id.btn_close);
                btn_close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        dialog_edit_ava.dismiss(); 
                    }
                });

                Button btn_continue = (Button) dialog_edit_ava.findViewById(R.id.btn_continue);
                btn_continue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        dialog_edit_ava.dismiss(); 
                    }
                });
                dialog_edit_ava.show();
            }


        });

        btn_edit_email.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Dialog dialog_edit_email;
                dialog_edit_email = new Dialog(EditProfile.this);
                dialog_edit_email.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                dialog_edit_email.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_edit_email); 
                dialog_edit_email.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT)); 
                dialog_edit_email.setCancelable(false); 

                
                TextView btn_close = (TextView) dialog_edit_email.findViewById(R.id.btn_close);
                btn_close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        dialog_edit_email.dismiss(); 
                    }
                });

                //кнопка продолжить
                Button btn_continue = (Button) dialog_edit_email.findViewById(R.id.btn_continue);
                btn_continue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        //ОШИБКА!!!!!!!!!!
                        String emailStr = emailEt.getText().toString();
                        
                        String type = "emailEt";
                        new BackgroundWorkerEditP(EditProfile.this, type, log, emailStr);


                        dialog_edit_email.dismiss(); 
                });
                dialog_edit_email.show();
            }


        });

        btn_edit_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Dialog dialog_edit_login;
                dialog_edit_login = new Dialog(EditProfile.this);
                dialog_edit_login.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
                dialog_edit_login.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_edit_login); 
                dialog_edit_login.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT)); 
                dialog_edit_login.setCancelable(false); 
              
                TextView btn_close = (TextView) dialog_edit_login.findViewById(R.id.btn_close);
                btn_close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        dialog_edit_login.dismiss(); 
                    }
                });

               
                Button btn_continue = (Button) dialog_edit_login.findViewById(R.id.btn_continue);
                btn_continue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        //ОШИБКА!!!!!!!!!!
                        String questionStr = questionEdit.getText().toString();
                        String answerStr = answerEdit.getText().toString();
                        
                        String type = "questionEt";
                        new BackgroundWorkerEditP(EditProfile.this, type, log, questionStr);
                        type = "answerEt";
                        new BackgroundWorkerEditP(EditProfile.this, type, log, answerStr);
                        dialog_edit_login.dismiss(); //закрываем диалоговое окно
                    }
                });
                dialog_edit_login.show();
            }
        });

        btn_edit_name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Dialog dialog_edit_name;
                dialog_edit_name = new Dialog(EditProfile.this);
                dialog_edit_name.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
                dialog_edit_name.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_edit_name); 
                dialog_edit_name.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT)); //прозрачный фон диалогового окна
                dialog_edit_name.setCancelable(false); 

                TextView btn_close = (TextView) dialog_edit_name.findViewById(R.id.btn_close);
                btn_close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        dialog_edit_name.dismiss(); 
                    }
                });

               
                Button btn_continue = (Button) dialog_edit_name.findViewById(R.id.btn_continue);
                btn_continue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        //ОШИБКА!!!!!!!!!!
                        String nicknameStr = nicknameEt.getText().toString();
                      
                        String type = "nicknameEt";
                        new BackgroundWorkerEditP(EditProfile.this, type, log, nicknameStr);

                        dialog_edit_name.dismiss(); 
                    }
                });
                dialog_edit_name.show();
            }
        });
        btn_edit_password.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Dialog dialog_edit_password;
                dialog_edit_password = new Dialog(EditProfile.this);
                dialog_edit_password.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
                dialog_edit_password.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_edit_password); 
                dialog_edit_password.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT)); 
                dialog_edit_password.setCancelable(false); 

                
                TextView btn_close = (TextView) dialog_edit_password.findViewById(R.id.btn_close);
                btn_close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        dialog_edit_password.dismiss(); 
                    }
                });

                
                Button btn_continue = (Button) dialog_edit_password.findViewById(R.id.btn_continue);
                btn_continue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        //ОШИБКА!!!!!!!!!!
                        String passwordStr = passwordEt.getText().toString();
                       
                        String type = "passwordEt";
                        new BackgroundWorkerEditP(EditProfile.this, type, log, passwordStr);

                        dialog_edit_password.dismiss(); 
                    }
                });
                dialog_edit_password.show();
            }
        });
    }


   
    public void onBackPressed(){
        Intent back = new Intent (EditProfile.this, MainProfile.class);
        back.putExtra("log",log);
        back.putExtra("avatar",avatar);
        startActivity(back);
        finish();
    }
}
```

xml файл основного окна

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/edit_profile"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_back"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/back" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ava"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/style_profile_edit"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/lamb"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
               />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_edit_email"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background = "@drawable/style_btn"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:text="@string/edit_email"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textAllCaps="false"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_edit_login"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:background="@drawable/style_btn"
                android:text="@string/edit_QA"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_edit_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background = "@drawable/style_btn"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:text="@string/edit_name"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textAllCaps="false"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_edit_password"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background = "@drawable/style_btn"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:text="@string/edit_password"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textAllCaps="false"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

xml файл одного диалогового окна (остальные сделаны по тому же принципу)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:id="@+id/rules_dialog"
    android:background="@drawable/edit_password"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dp"

        >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/btn_close"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/x"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp">


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/passwordEdit"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="text" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_continue"
            android:layout_width="55dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="@string/ok"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/pink"
            android:textSize="13sp"/>

    </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
EditText passwordEt,
EditText emailEt;
EditText questionEdit;
EditText answerEdit;
EditText nicknameEt;
```

должны принадлежать (быть объявлены в xml разметке)

```
R.layout.edit_profile
```

У вас они в других окнах, активити или фрагмент. Вот там и нужно их объявлять

Comment: Не очень понимаю, что конкретно мне надо сделать?  
`dialog_edit_password.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_edit_password); ` Вот здесь нужный мне layout ставлю, пытался объявить в следующей строке как `EditText passwordEt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordEt);` все равно возвращается null

Comment: Я поооонял как мне надо это сделать
`dialog_edit_password.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_edit_password);`
`EditText passwordEt = (EditText) dialog_edit_password.findViewById(R.id.passwordEt);`